# Transmit DataMember with large Strings

Tags: c#, wcf

In a wcf-Application (.NET FW 4.0) hosted in IIS 8.0 I would like to send as parameter a complex DataMember with two large Strings. These strings can be up to 20 or more MB. First I used transferMode=Streamed, but I always got the error:

> *Additional information: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to
>   deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:request. The InnerException
>   message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type
>   QCheckerService.Parameter. The maximum string content length quota
>   (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be
>   increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the
>   XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.*

I set the readerQuotas all to max in the config file. But the error is concerning the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas. Is there a way to avoid changing these latter quotas in the code?

I am a bit confused now what could be a suitable solution. Is the default transferMode=Buffered the right way to do this?

Or is the transmission of large strings impossible and I should use another way?

If I transmit small strings, it works. Here the additional configurations.

client app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <client>
    <endpoint address=http://localhost:12412/Service1.svc 
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IQChecker"
              contract="QCheckerService.IQChecker"> 
  </client>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IQChecker" 
                     maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
                     maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                     transferMode="Streamed">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                      maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                      maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                      maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                      maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

service web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="Basic"
               maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
               maxBufferSize="2147483647"
               maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
               transferMode="Streamed">
        <readerQuotas maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                      maxDepth="32"
                      maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                      maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                      maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Service Interface for relevant DataMember

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "MyMethod", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
ReturnValue MyMethod (Parameter request);

[DataContract]
public class Parameter: IDisposable
{
    [DataMember]
    String String1;

    [DataMember]
    String String2;

    public void SetString1(String drawing)
    {
        String1 = drawing;
    }

    public String GetString1()
    {
        return String1;
    }

    public void SetString2(String configuration)
    {
        String2 = configuration;
    }

    public String GetString2()
    {
        return String2;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
```

Thank you for some advice.

Comment: If you want a proper answer, include your relevant web.config settings and at least a method signature.

Comment: The problem is probably in the client configuration, so include the client config file as well.

Comment: The exception message appears to spell out precisely what the issue is.

Comment: You don't have an endpoint defined in your server config?

Comment: No, for localhost it works without.

Answer (score 0):

In your service's config file, you have defined a `basicHttpBinding` with a name of "Basic".  However, you have no endpoint for the service explicitly defined, so by default the framework will expose an endpoint with `basicHttpBinding` at the location of the service file.  This default endpoint will use the **default** values for `basicHttpBinding` - in other words, the binding you defined is not used at all.

Two ways to fix this (in WCF 4.0+):  You must either a) assign that binding by it's name to an explicit endpoint (which is also defined in the config file) or b) set it up as the default binding for that transport protocol.

For option a, you would add an endpoint to your service's config file:

```
<services>
  <service name="Your service name">
    <endpoint address="" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="Basic" 
              contract="QCheckerService.IQChecker" />
  </service>
</services>
```

For option b, you can make the configuration you specified as the default by ommitting the `name` attribute on the binding definition, like this:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             transferMode="Streamed">
      <readerQuotas maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxDepth="32"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

The above binding definition will be used for all services using that configuration file and `basicHttpBinding`.

For more information on default bindings, endpoints and behaviors, see [A Developer's Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx)